# oltpbenchmark scale parameter for tpcc over mysql

Tags: mysql, oltp

What exactly does the "scale" parameter does in oltpbenchmark tool does (for tpcc when being run on mysql)?
does it only increase the size of the DB? or does it do something else?

(http://oltpbenchmark.com)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the number of rows of the WAREHOUSE table which is used as the base unit of scaling. The cardinality of all other tables (except for ITEM) is a function of the number of configured warehouses (i.e., cardinality of the WAREHOUSE table). That's the reason it increase the size of your DB when you increase the scale factor.

For TPC-C you have the follow cardinalities:

[image: For TPC-C you have the follow cardinalities:]